# Как читать данные из файла что бы их закодировать?

Tags: c++, ascii

У меня есть файл это может быть не обязательно `jpg`, файл может быть любой.

Я хочу через программу открыть этот файл и сжать его, используя что то свое.
Для этого мне надо открыть файл, это вроде я понял как сделать, далее мне нужно вытащить его код что бы изменить его на свой, я же верно думаю.

Вот что я сделал.

```
int main() {

    std::ifstream fs("1.jpg");

    if (fs) {
        std::cout << " Yes " << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << " No " << std::endl;
    }

    char s;


    for (fs >> s; !fs.eof(); fs >> s)
        std::cout << s;

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

на выходе я получаю какой то код, а консоль у меня пикает, я думаю это `ASCII`, я не совсем уверен что `ASCII` это правильно, может надо выводить его по другому.
Иначе как я смогу каждый символ в файле перекодировать на свои ключи?
А возможно я все не верно делаю подскажите кто знает.

Кароче говоря мне нужно реализовать сжатия и перекодировать файл в свой стиль например восьмеричный, шестнадцатеричный но скорее всего что то уникально.

Comment: а вы хотите чтобы при чтении jpg файла у вас нормальный текст выводился?

Comment: @timur нет я хочу взять получается код этого файла, наверно это байт код или машинный код не знаю, и каждый символ этого кода перекодировать в свой код.
Я думаю как раз таким способом и сжимают данные.

Comment: Открывайте с помощью [binary](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/openmode)

Comment: @dIm0n а можно пример как открыть?

Comment: @viski [в самом низу](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream)

Comment: Используй не `operator bool`, а `is_open`.

Comment: Капец запустл теперь процесс завершить не могу он вечно пикает)

Comment: @viski на вашем месте, я бы не показывал "текст" в консоли - сохраните этот "текст" хотя бы в тот же .txt, чтобы увидеть что из этого выйдет. Для того чтобы хотя бы иметь какое-то представление, что вам покажет файл, рекомендую ознакомится хотя бы с тем, как работает тот же .BMP https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP ну и сообственно https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG

Comment: Используйте [`.get()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get) вместо `>>`, а то последний пропускает пробелы. (Или вызывайте `std::noskipws`.)

Answer (score 2):

Начнем с того, что байт - это 8 бит, с помощью которых можно закодировать значения

от 0 - 00000000b (0x00)
до 255 - 11111111b (0xFF)

Каждому из этих значений есть свое применение, например:

65 - 01000001b (0x41) - это большая буква 'A' латинского алфавита, а 122 - 01111010b (0x7A) - это маленькая буква 'z'.

Но не все коды соответствуют символам, которые можно отобразить, есть ещё категория управляющих символов, нопример 7 - 00000111b (0x07) - этот символ называется BEL (или bell) и означает звуковой сигнал - тот самый, который вы пытаетесь вывести на экран и слышите писк динамика.

Подробнее о назначении всех символов можно почитать тут https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII

чтобы выводить именно коды на экран, необходимо открыть файл с флагом [binary](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/openmode), а при выводе в консоль привести тип к int - тогда он будет отображаться как число (тот самый код символа).

Comment: *байт - это 8 бит* — точнее октет; стоит ещё добавить, что C++ не гарантирует, что символ `'A'` имеет код `65`, поэтому лучше не полагаться на такое поведение